# creating a SQLite Backup on root of SD card

Tags: android, sqlite

How can I backup my `SQLiteDatabase` on the root of my SD card instead of  `com.jti.mikee.jti_pos`. because the problem that I've encountering right now is when i uninstall the app. the package name on SD Card was removed. even the sql backups. I'm developing on a device android `4.4`

This is my code for back up a database:

```
private void DBBackup() {
    try {
        File[] sd = getContext().getExternalFilesDirs(null);
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd[1].canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "/data/com.jti.mikee.jti_pos/databases/" + DBHelper.DB_NAME;
            String backupDBPath =DBHelper.DB_NAME;
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd[1], backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course that apps private folder will get removed, if the app is deinstalled. That is the point of deinstalling it. You certainly can copy any files you like to the sdcard, but they will be visible and everyone can tamper with those files in the public space. You can use normal file handling functions as offered by android/java for that, this works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

getContext().getExternalFilesDirs(null) returns somewhere on the SD card but still belongs to the application.

You should use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().

Answer (score 0):

this should return the internal storage at `[0]` and the external storage at `[1]`:

```
File[] paths = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(getContext(), null);
```

alternatively ...

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String path = sdcard.getAbsolutePath();
```

the `.getAbsolutePath()` might be the trick here - for both methods of obtaining the handle.

Comment: as of now its not working. how can I create an public folder for it?